# Proper way in ReactJS to restrict querySelectorAll and getElementsByClassName to component children

Tags: reactjs, dom

I have a class component (custom slider based on a POJO one) that I reuse many times in a page. I need to get a reference of the children (slides) and the container. The documentation suggest to use `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll` which brings every single element from the whole Document but I only need to get the elements inside the component. I understand I can use references and I know is an official feature but it looks "hacky" to me. Right now instead of keeping a reference I use `event.parentNode` to access the DOM and it looks cleaner. Right now it seems that I don't need it but I was wondering maybe due to my POJO background what is the proper way to do restrict this query to the component.

```
class SlideShowSection extends Component 
    {
    state =
                {
                    ...
                    //_slidesContainer = element.querySelector('.Slides-Container');
                    ...
                    
                }
        
    handleEvent = (event) => 
                {
                ...
                switch (event.type) 
                    {
                      ...
                      case 'touchmove':
                      event.target.parentNode.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + (-position * 100) + 'vw, 0, 0)'
                      break
                      ...
                    }
                }
      }
```